# Piecewise continuation of a discrete function on an area

Tags: function-construction, piecewise, discontinuity

I have a discrete function (finite set of values) defined on an area $\Omega$ in $R^2$. Each value of the function is defined on a subarea $\Omega_i$(triangle in my case). These triangles account for the whole area $\Omega=\bigcup \Omega_i$. I need create a new piecewise function which would be constant on each triangle, but defined on the $\Omega$. How one can do it?

I can define a piecewise function for distinct triangles. Then I have to union all of them into the single function. So, turning an array of piecewise functions into the single piecewise function would solve my problem.

For example:

```
n = 4;
tr1 = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.25, 0}, {0.125, 0.25}}];
tr2 = Triangle[{{0.25, 0}, {0.375, 0.25}, {0.125, 0.25}}];
tr3 = Triangle[{{0.25, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.375, 0.25}}];
tr4 = Triangle[{{0.125, 0.25}, {0.375, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.5}}];
tr = {tr1, tr2, tr3, tr4};
val = {1, 2, 3, 4};
f[x_, y_] = 
  Table[Piecewise[ {{val[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] 
       tr[[i]]} , {0, {x, y} ! \[Element] tr[[i]]}} ], {i, 1, n}];
```

I need the sole function, defined on $\bigcup tr_i$, which should be the sum of that four functions defined on $tr_i$:

```
g[x_, y_] = 
 Piecewise[ { {val[[1]], {x, y} \[Element] 
     tr[[1]]}, {val[[2]], {x, y} \[Element] 
     tr[[2]]}, {val[[3]], {x, y} \[Element] 
     tr[[3]]}, {val[[4]], {x, y} \[Element] tr[[4]]}  }]
```

In my problem $n$ is much bigger. How can I wrap it into a loop? Moreover, is it an effective way to create such a function? The command 
`Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 0.25}, {y, 0, 0.25}`] 
for example, works for too long.

Comment: So what is the question? How to union them? How about adding them together? Or define all the different triangles in one piecewise?

Comment: I've updated the question. I just need define a new function as a sum of other functions.

Comment: The question is how to define them into the one piecewise function

Comment: how about defining f like this:`f[x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[Table[{val[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] tr[[i]]}, {i, 1, n}]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define the table within the piecewise (inferring 0 unless otherwise specified) we get the following:

```
n = 4;
tr1 = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.25, 0}, {0.125, 0.25}}];
tr2 = Triangle[{{0.25, 0}, {0.375, 0.25}, {0.125, 0.25}}];
tr3 = Triangle[{{0.25, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.375, 0.25}}];
tr4 = Triangle[{{0.125, 0.25}, {0.375, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.5}}];
tr = {tr1, tr2, tr3, tr4};
val = {1, 2, 3, 4};
f[x_, y_] = 
Piecewise[Table[{val[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] tr[[i]]}, {i, 1, n}]];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 0.25}, {y, 0, 0.25}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

to get:

[image]

or to lower computing time:

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 0.25}, {y, 0, 0.25}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need. Is there any way to speed up the plotting? Or it is a price I should pay for working with such a function?

Comment: Could you advice how to get red of that gaps among regions?

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] = RegionUnion[tr1, tr2, tr3, tr4], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]

Comment: Would 'DensityPlot' work in your case? It would be a lot faster

Comment: I've tried it.  A bit faster. Gaps are what really worry me. I think, that performance will increase when I get red of them.

Comment: If your only interested in a graph I would look into `Graphics` and `Triangle`,plotting would not be the way to go for large n

Comment: FYI, you can trade accuracy for speed by lowering `PlotPoints`

Comment: Okay. I've realized that those gaps depend on accuracy, and it's a price I have to pay for acceleration. It's not very good. The union of subareas is only necessary for plotting data. For DensityPlot or ContourPlot one can try to specify the color directly for each triangle. I will look in this direction now.